# How to dynamically create a non-variadic function (without eval or similar)?

Tags: python, arguments

#### Overview

At some point at run-time, I want to create a function that **exactly** takes a given number of arguments (known only at run-time). *Exactly* here means that this must not be a variadic function. Is there any way to do this without resorting to `eval` or similar ways to interpret strings as code?

#### My problem (slightly reduced)

I want to create a function that takes its arguments and passes them to another function as an iterable. Usually, I could do this as follows:

```
my_function = lambda *args: other_function(args)
```

Unfortunately, `my_function` will be called by some routine that cannot properly handle variadic functions¹. However, `my_function` will always be called with the same number of arguments `n_args`. So, if I knew `n_args` to be 3, I could use:

```
my_function = lambda a,b,c: other_function((a,b,c))
```

The problem is that I only get to know `n_args` at run-time, just before creating `my_function`. Thus, I need to generalise the above.

#### What I found so far

- I achieve what I want using `eval` (or `exec` or similar):

  ```
  arg_string = ",".join( "arg_%i"%i for i in range(n_args) )
  my_function = eval(
          "lambda %s: other_function((%s))" % (arg_string,arg_string),
          {"other_function":other_function}
      )
  ```

  The downside to this is that I have to use `eval`, [which is ugly and bad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/2127008). If you so wish, my question is how to create something equivalent to the above without using `eval` or obtaining a variadic function.
- [SymPy’s `lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) allows me to dynamically create functions with a fixed number of arguments at run-time (that work in my context), but looking at the source code, it seems that it uses `eval` under the hood as well.

---

<sup>¹ It’s a compiled routine created with F2Py. I cannot change this with reasonable effort right now. Yes, it’s sad and on the long run, I will find try to fix this or get this fixed, but for now let’s accept this as given.</sup>

Comment: Rejoice, because you can unpack and pack arguments as you please. For example, `other_function(*args)` is the same as `other_function(a, b, c)` at runtime.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: *is the same* – Not to the routines that call my function. That’s exactly my problem.

Comment: If you can call those routines from python, then you can use `*`, unless you're using python1. This really isn't enough to go on, and as it stands, I don't think there's another way to do this besides eval.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Those routines are not called from Python (but some compiled C-API code or similar) and I cannot control how they are being called.

Comment: Surely there is a wrapper? Was this written in pyrex? cython?

Comment: I imagine you could do something by way of AST mangling. That's less gross than `eval`... but "less gross than `eval`" doesn't say much.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: See my edit.

Comment: I take it that the place these functions are being called aren't able to construct some sort of tuple or list themselves?

Comment: @AlexHall: Correct. If I could (easily) address this, I would have done so already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function like the below. You can write a script to generate the code dynamically to make it as long as you want, but still keep the result statically in a normal python file to avoid using eval/exec.

```
def function_maker(n_args, other_function):
    return [
        lambda: other_function(),
        lambda arg_0: other_function(arg_0),
        lambda arg_0, arg_1: other_function(arg_0, arg_1),
    ][n_args]
```

Then use it as follows:

```
function_maker(2, other_function)(a, b)
```